# Using django-ipware get_client_ip instead of get_real_ip

Tags: python, django, ip

In django-ipware version 2.1 ; old `get_real_ip` function is deprecated. When I use the new `get_client_ip` ; my test units are not showing the same results. Means that the two functions do not behave the same.

The following is an original test from django-ipware test unit (not mine)

```
def test_http_x_forwarded_for_multiple(self):
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.META = {
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '192.168.255.182, 10.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, 198.84.193.157, 177.139.233.139',
        'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '177.139.233.132',
        'REMOTE_ADDR': '177.139.233.133',
    }
    ip = get_real_ip(request)
    self.assertEqual(ip, "198.84.193.157")
```

The above works fine of course, but I want to ensure that using the new `get_client_ip` will give the same results (for a system upgrade purposes). But the test is actually failing the assertion:

```
def test_http_x_forwarded_for_multiple(self):
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.META = {
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '192.168.255.182, 10.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, 198.84.193.157, 177.139.233.139',
        'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '177.139.233.132',
        'REMOTE_ADDR': '177.139.233.133',
    }
    ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
    self.assertEqual(ip, "198.84.193.157")
```

resulting:

**AssertionError: '177.139.233.132' != '198.84.193.157'**

After digging into the code, I found that the new `get_client_ip` is not iterating inside the meta like `get_real_ip` . It checks out the left-most ip (or right-most depending on the settings) and skips to the next meta if a **Public IP** is not found

My question(s) now are:
How can I call `get_client_ip` in a way that returns the same ip returned by `get_real_ip` ? What is the logic behind changing the behavior of the function ? Should I trust the new `get_client_ip` and forget about `get_real_ip`, or keep using the deprecated `get_real_ip` and forget about the new `get_client_ip` ?????

Comment: I wounder if @un33k can give a clarification for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should forget about the old `get_real_ip` function and its behavior. See author's reply here: https://github.com/un33k/django-ipware/issues/45#issuecomment-421572304